# Please teach me how to fix errors shown on Google Insights

Tags: wordpress

I keep getting multiple errors when I check my site on Google Page Insights. It is a wordpress site.

My url: www.vrsyndicate.com
Installed Plugins: W3 Cache Plugin (Minify CSS, JS defaultly enabled)

Codes I added to .htaccess: php compression, gzip compression, cache expiry

Problems: Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content, Minify CSS, Leverage Browser Caching, Optimize Images

Thanks

Comment: You can load you javascript Asynchronously to prevent it from blocking the rest of the page. I had [written in the past how to do it](http://idiallo.com/javascript/async-js).

Answer (score -1):

**Your question is not related to stackoverflow**... but i will help you.

This plugins should help alot if you are not familiar with hand made coding.

To eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/above-the-fold-optimization/

To minifinf CSS and JS:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-minify/

To leverage Browser Caching:

https://ro.wordpress.org/plugins/leverage-browser-caching-ninjas/

To optimize Images:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/